# Git clone shows few directories as empty; though on github.com they are non-empty

Tags: git, github

When I do git clone; few directories are empty.. but when I browse through same directories on github.com they are non-empty ! Also, on github.com there is a special sign ( not a folder ) one for these directories.. Looks like it is getting code from somewhere else ( some other repository ).

How do I get source code of those directories also when I do git clone.

Answer here was keyword submodule..Once I know this keyword; I can easily find answer trying to google.

Comment: Is it a submodule? Try running `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: Yes u are right.. Thanks for help. Can you make this as answer instead of comment